# Laptop brightness changing even without adaptive brightness

Tags: laptop, brightness, hp-pavilion

I have turned adaptive brightness off but it still keeps changing, this only started happening recently.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please review [this page](http://superuser.com/tour) and consider editing your post to provide more detail about the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail it's hard to give a definitive answer, but it COULD be a faulty screen.

I had a monitor do this to me and it was the screen beginning to die.

My advice - BACK-UP YOUR DATA to a portable drive (which is good practice anyway) so if you have to send the laptop off for repairs, your data is safe!